# How to disable hiberbate logs in Catalina.out

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, log4j

I'm using log4j 1.x. The catalina.out file in my web applicatio gets bigger in no time in the server.

Here is the snippet of my log4j.properties file:

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=INFO, hb
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=ERROR, hb
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=ERROR, hb
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.hql.ast.AST=DEBUG, hb
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl=DEBUG, hb
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.hql=DEBUG, hb
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.cache=DEBUG, hb
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.jdbc=DEBUG, hb

#log4j.logger.jdbc.sqltiming = DEBUG, file
log4j.additivity.jdbc.sqltiming = false
log4j.additivity.org.hibernate = false
log4j.additivity.org.hibernate.SQL = false
log4j.additivity.org.hibernate.type = false
log4j.additivity.org.hibernate.hql.ast.AST = false
log4j.additivity.org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl = false
log4j.additivity.org.hibernate.hql = false
log4j.additivity.org.hibernate.cache = false
log4j.additivity.org.hibernate.jdbc = false
log4j.additivity.com.pip.png.api.audit = false
log4j.additivity.com.pip.png.api.audit.rules = false
log4j.additivity.com.pip.png.api.audit.validator = false
log4j.additivity.com.pip.png.api.tibco = false
log4j.additivity.com.pip.png.api.tibco.listener = false
```

AS per this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42728862/control-sql-logging-level-in-catalina-out), I added `<property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>` in my persistence.xml file  but that did not help either.

How can I fix this? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311408/turning-off-hibernate-logging-console-output):

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=info

//for xml configuration
<logger name="org.hibernate">
  <level value="info"/> 
</logger>
```

or programmatically:

```
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.hibernate").setLevel(Level.OFF);
```

or see if there are solutions that suit you

Comment: That's the first line of the code snippet shared. Isn't it?

Comment: how about the second approach under "programmatically", I guess it serves your purpose